# Solr: At what index size should I start considering splitting up the indexes with sharding

Tags: solr

I've got 120GB of input data indexed currently (not storing data, just doc IDs & the indexes), it takes somewhere on the order of 12+ hrs to index the full data set.

We haven't yet moved that into production, what I want to know is what point will I need to start considering sharding, separating the index onto multiple servers?

Is sharding your index a question of index size, or is it only a question of indexing time/disk space/user load?

Will I run into memory limitations as my index grows to say 200GB, 300GB of input data, etc?